# What distinguishes a user story/feature from a use case/scenario?

Tags: cucumber, specflow, specifications, gherkin, speclog

What distinguishes a user story/feature from a use case/scenario? Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Is it just the granularity, similar to epics and user stories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much has already been written on the meanings of and difference between "use case" and "user story". [Google "stackoverflow difference between use case and user story"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow%20difference%20between%20use%20case%20and%20user%20story) to see some of it.

Regarding "feature" and "scenario":

- In Gherkin, a Scenario is a series of steps that are executed together.

  - In terms of user stories: it might take one or many Scenarios to specify a user story, depending on the size of the story.
  - In terms of use cases: Gherkin's use of "scenario" corresponds almost exactly to the meaning of "scenario" in use case analysis: A use case describes a series of interactions between an actor (usually but not always a human user) and the system, in enough detail to make the system's responsibilities clear; a scenario is an instance of that use case with some values and the resulting details of interactions exactly specified, with the purpose of making some fine point of the system's responsibility (often edge case or error handling) clear. Just like a use case scenario, a Gherkin Scenario necessarily specifies all values completely (even if they're hidden in step definitions and not visible in the Gherkin itself), so "Scenario" was a good choice of name for that Gherkin concept.
- A Gherkin Feature is just a collection of Scenarios, which you can use however you like.

  - In terms of user stories: A Feature can be the set of Scenarios that implement a user story or epic. In my experience, after more than one story has been implemented that touches the same part of an application (the same "feature"), one wants to put the Scenarios for those stories in the same Feature so one knows where to find them -- for example, you might want to put all the Scenarios related to user accounts (create an account, upgrade a subscription plan, cancel an account) in the same Feature rather than in different features, even though they implement quite different stories.
  - In terms of use cases: It usually takes several Scenarios to specify a use case (e.g. one for the happy path and one for an error path). Clearly these belong together in the same Feature file. As with user stories, one often wants to put the Scenarios for use cases that describe the same feature of the software in the same Feature.